# Get corresponding playlists for tracks that have been favorited on SoundCloud

Tags: api, soundcloud

I am trying to build a website that among other things pulls favorites from my soundcloud page. Due to SoundCloud's terrible genre tags I have created playlists that I would like to use for genre tags on my site. I currently have the following code which loads the URL's of 200 of my most recent favorites (code does not include SC.initialize for security purposes)

I would like to pull the playlists each song has been added to as text next to the URL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
  var userId = 68219117; // user_id of BeetsnBass

  SC.get("/users/68219117/favorites", {
      user_id: userId,
      limit: 200
  }, function (tracks) {

      var tmp = '';

      for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {

          tmp = tracks[i].permalink_url;

          $("<table/>").html(tmp).appendTo("#track-list");
      }
      
      var **playlist** = '';

      for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {

          **playlist** = tracks[i].**playlist**;

          $("<table/>").html(**playlist**).appendTo("#genre");
      }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="track-list"><td/>
            <td id="genre"><td/>
                <tr/>
                <table/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats should work:

```
var userid = 68219117;
var limit = 200;

SC.get("/users/"+userid+"/favorites", {limit: limit}, function (tracks) {
      for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
          getTrackPlaylists(tracks[i].id, tracks[i].permalink_url);    
        }  
});

function getTrackPlaylists(trackid, url){
SC.get("/tracks/" + trackid + "/playlists", function (playlists) {
      for (var i = 0; i < playlists.length; i++) {
          genre = '';
    if(playlists[i].user.id == 68219117){
     console.log(playlists[i].title);   
    genre = playlists[i].title;
   $("<table/>").html(url).appendTo("#track-list");
   $("<table/>").html(genre).appendTo("#genre");
    }
      }    
});
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/hh9b71px/6/

You may have to add some fallbacks and error handling, pagination..

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm not really sure how to implement what you've given me into my existing code. I've tried manipulating it into a similar format but have not been successful..

Comment: i have added some code. on top, i would use jqueries add class method and add the track id as class - then you can use this as a reference to add the genres properly.

Comment: Yes! It's almost perfect. I'm looking to pull only the playlists I have added the songs to. This seems to be pulling all of the playlists the track has been added to

Comment: Now it pulls the name of only one random playlist associated with the track. The `if (playlists[i].user.id = 68219117) ` does not seem to be doing anything

Comment: Nope, no luck with that either. The code is indeed pulling my favorites and pulling the playlists that these favorited tracks have been added to. Yet, the favorites are being pulled in a random order AND the playlists are random ones that the tracks have been added to, not ones from my account. Additionally, the results only show 8 tracks while the limit is 50